# remove speical string from lines richtextbox vb.net

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

i have a richtextbox with many lines like this `Batman=games\file.exe

> Batman=games\file\spid.exe
>
> SNaruto=games\file\spid.exe
>
> spiderman=blue\spk.exe
>
> game=gigi.exe

i'm trying to make button delete every texts after **=** to be like this

> Batman
>
> SNaruto
>
> spiderman
>
> game

or even

> Batman=
>
> SNaruto=
>
> spiderman=
>
> game=

thanks

Comment: You can have use of the `String.IndexOf` method: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwb0bwyd(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thank you ,But I am new in this area
Can you give me an example ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you are lucky, i've been working since morning for similar code to what you want, here we go I made some changes on my code to fit ur request

```
Dim x As String = ""
        Dim y As String = ""
        For Each strLine As String In TextBox1.Text.Split(vbNewLine) 'TO read each line in text box
            Dim ii As Integer = strLine.Length
            Dim i As Integer = 0
            For i = 0 To ii - 1
                y = strLine.Substring(i, 1)
                If y = "=" Then
                    x = strLine.Substring(0, i)
                    TextBox2.AppendText(x & Environment.NewLine)
                End If
            Next
        Next
```

Comment: Both the TextBox and the RichTextBox have got the `Lines` array property where each element is one line in the text. So to read each line you just loop through the array. Also, you can use the `String.Chars` array for strings to get each character instead of using Substring on every character. This code eats more RAM and processor usage than needed too. I recommend you to read this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.lines%28v=vs.110%29.aspx and this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.chars%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: I meant to say "This code you're using" instead of just "This code". What I like with your code though is that you've managed to solve a problem using your own ways. (:

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
For x = 0 To RichTextBox1.Lines.Length - 1
    Dim i As Integer = RichTextBox1.Lines(x).IndexOf("=")
    If i <> -1 Then
        RichTextBox1.Lines(x) = RichTextBox1.Lines(x).Remove(i)
    End If
Next
```

**A little explanation regarding the properties and methods used:**

The `RichTextBox.Lines()` property is an array of strings where each element/object represents one line in the RichTextBox. **Read more:** https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.lines(v=vs.110).aspx

The `IndexOf` method returns the index of a character or a string inside the specified string. And if nothing was found, it returns `-1`. To errors we check so that `IndexOf` does not return `-1`. That's why we use `If i <> -1 Then`, where `<>` means "Not equal to". **Read more:** https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.indexof(v=vs.110).aspx

The `Remove` method will remove an amount characters from the specified string, starting at the specified start position. It will then remove all the characters including, and after, the one at the specified start position. **Read more:** https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.remove%28v=vs.110%29.aspx